# Plotting bipartite graph from adjacency matrix

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

I have an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ representing the adjacencies between the nodes of a bipartite graph. Specifically, the nodes are arranged in two partitions, of $m$ and $n$ nodes respectively, such that $A_{ij}\ne 0$ if and only if there is an edge between nodes $i$ and $j$. Moreover, if $A_{ij}\ne 0$, I would like to display the number $A_{ij}$ next to the edge connecting $i,j$. The nodes from the two partitions should have distinct colors, so I can differentiate the partitions.

What I have managed to do thus far is to display the graph, by constructing an $(m+n)\times (m+n)$ block matrix:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & A\\
A^{T} & 0
\end{array}\right)$$

and passing it as argument to `AdjacencyGraph`. Explicitly, this is my code so far:

```
MatToGraph[mat_?MatrixQ] := 
 ArrayFlatten[{{0, mat}, {Transpose[mat], 0}}] /. _?(# != 0 &) -> 1 //
   AdjacencyGraph
```

Comment: Here's a trick with `ArrayFlatten`: you can replace those `ConstantArray[0, ...]` expressions with a simple `0` for easier typing and better readability.

Comment: @Szabolcs +1 cool! Thanks! I'll edit your fix into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

other possible way:

```
matToGraph[mat_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Block[{bmat = SparseArray[mat], m, n, eweight, edges},
  {m, n} = Dimensions[bmat];
  eweight = bmat["NonzeroValues"];
  edges = UndirectedEdge[#1, #2 + m] & @@@ bmat["NonzeroPositions"];
  Graph[Range[m + n], edges, EdgeWeight -> eweight, opts, 
   GraphLayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding", 
   VertexStyle -> {Red, _?(# > m &) -> Blue}, 
   EdgeLabels -> 
    MapThread[#1 -> Placed[#2, {1/5, {1/2, 1/2}}] &, {edges, 
      eweight}], EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[Italic, 18]]
  ]

testmat = RandomInteger[{0, 3}, {5, 3}];
matToGraph[testmat, VertexSize -> .5, 
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
 VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[White, 18], 
 EdgeStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
matToGraph[mat_?MatrixQ, col1_, col2_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
   With[{am = SparseArray[ArrayFlatten[{{0, mat}, {Transpose[mat], 0}}]], 
        dims = Dimensions[mat]}, 
   AdjacencyGraph[Unitize@am, GraphLayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding",
   VertexStyle ->Join[Thread[Range[dims[[1]]] -> col1], 
                      Thread[Range[dims[[1]] + 1, dims[[1]] + dims[[2]]] -> col2]], 
   VertexSize -> Medium, 
   EdgeLabels -> Thread[(UndirectedEdge @@@ am["NonzeroPositions"]) -> 
       (Placed[Style[#, 16, Purple], {1/5, {1/2, 1/2}}] & /@ am["NonzeroValues"])], 
  FilterRules[{opts}, Options[AdjacencyGraph]]]]

  testmat = RandomInteger[{0, 2}, {5, 3}];
  matToGraph[testmat, Red, Blue,EdgeStyle -> Thick, 
         VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", {Center, Center}], ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: The default options are not working.

Comment: @becko, are you getting an error message?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. But if don't explicitly specify the colors, the nodes all show in the default gray colors. To get bipartite red and blue colors, I have to explicitly set those optional arguments. I don't know why this happens.

Comment: @becko, could not get the optional color args work properly; so I changed the optional color arguments to required arguments.

Comment: weird; maybe its a bug

Comment: @becko, not quite sure but it may be that optional arguments and options do not mix...